# Aurelia tutorial stuck building out contact list

Tags: aurelia

I'm an experienced WPF developer, but new to web development.

I'm stuck at point where you replace the Contact List Placeholder
with the contact-list custom element.

When I run it the web page still shows the placeholder text instead of the contact list.  I assumed this was a cache issue, but I've tried everything I can think of to clear the cache. I have also tried deleting the app.html and running the site to see what kind of error I'd get, but still I get the template with Contact List Placeholder. I've tried reverting to the original  tag and changing the inner text, and I still get "Contact List Placeholder".

Comment: If no one can help you by tmw morning, I'll do my best to help, but I'm in an airport right now so hard to help from here.

Comment: Are you using the CLI? Try checking the bundle to see if it's picking up the edited view templates. Just add some random text to the view then build and search the app bundle for the text you added. If the watch task broke it often leads to this confusing "why aren't my changes being picked up" moment

Comment: I was opening the index.html file in Firefox.  I will start over using the CLI exclusively and see what happens and report back here.  (Ultimately I'd like to use Visual Studio 2015.)